# How to update an already distributed app without installing a new version

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I built a small application that gives real time update on coronavirus cases in my country.

Just recently, the API which I used to get the number of cases, deaths etc changed their endpoints
e.g from

```
https://covid19.com/corona/country
```

to

```
https://covid19.com/v2/corona/country
```

Due to strict restictions by Google on apps relating to covid19,  I couldnt upload to playstore but I built an APK and shared the link to many people to download.

Now, they cant access the number of cases in the app due to a change in the API endpoints.

Please, how do I change just that string URL from my end to have effect on everyone who has the app already without needing to build another apk and making people to download the app again.

I discovered **Firebase Remote Config**, I tried it on my android studio, run the app on my phone, and yes it was working on my device, but How do I get it to work on other people devices with the app already installed.??

Comment: no way! you need to make a new release with your config set. moreover if i would have been at your place i would put default API values in app and keep syncing API endpoints once in 24 hours from my database. its a good practice.

Comment: I am curious to know, in what situation does Firebase Remote Config works.?? cause it seems as tho, thats what it was built for.?

Comment: no firebase remote config is fore new feature roll outs. lets say you have changed something in the app like the main layout or the navigation of the app and then you souldn't be rolling it out for everyone instead roll it out slowly by targetting certain % of users and then look for their feedback, bugs and other user behaviours and then slowly you should be make it available for everyone. you might have seen big compaines like facebook instagram and whatsapp.

Comment: they relase features in different places at different times. they might be having their own version of remote config. but thats the use case of remote config.

Comment: so, are those "certain % of users" going to download an updated version of the app, or not?? and according to their website **"You can use Firebase Remote Config to define parameters in your app and update their values in the cloud, allowing you to modify the appearance and behavior of your app without distributing an app update."**

Comment: well everyone ll be updating their app but the new features ll be shown acccording to the  configuration data in remote database thats why the name `remote config`. now lets say you release it today with new navigation in the app and lets say you me and other 10 people are the users of the app. so you would set a config that only you and me see the new nagivation by default. and rest others see the older one. and when we both give positve feedback about it. you start changing your remote config so that another 5 users can see the new nagivation and it being done on the basis of remote config.

Comment: and when almost everyone is happy new navigation is being served to everyone. you can use this to change APIs as well but this is not for what remote config is built for ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only option you have is:
If you have put any text field which takes string data dynamically (like from database/server), there you can inform user to download latest version with a short link. But again that depends upon the text view size/scope you have defined.

Since, without updating the app itself by anyway, it seems impossible to make the existing app working.